# Can I use webview as a screen background in react native? If yes, How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to use a webview as a screen background in react native. Help if this is possible. I have used container, content from nativebase.io

```
<Container>
  <Content>
    <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://abc.xyz/'}}
      style={{height:"100%", width:"100%"}}
    />
    <Button title="button on top of webview" style={{position:"absolute",zIndex:-9999}}/>
  </Content>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. All you do is create a WebView set it to cover the full screen using absolute positioning then draw all your other elements over the top. Set the z-index at like -9999.

I won't help with the code but if you try and fail post your code and I can help :)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I tried the way you suggested but coudn't achieve what I was looking for. Can you please have a look at my code.

Comment: Try this.... also the button -9999 zindex will put the button behind everything. You need to overlay the button on top. Example style is below the view...

<View style={{ height: 100%, width:100% }}>
      <WebView
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        source={{uri: 'https://abc.xyz/'}}
      />
    </View>


submitButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom:0,
    left:0,
}

Comment: Additionally it's probably better to have the wrapping view as absolute instead of the button, then you can use normal flex layout for everything except the background. Otherwise you need to absolute position everything which I wouldn't recommend.